# Linear independence of $\{\exp(b_{n}z):n\in\mathbb N\}$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I have the following question:

1. Prove that the set $\{\exp(b_{n}z):n\in\mathbb N\}$ is linearly independent for some complex point $z\in\mathbb Z$.
2. Prove that the set $\{\exp(b_{n}z):n\in\mathbb N\}$ is linearly independent for all $z\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: What is $b_n$ (a priori we might have $b_n=0$ for all $n$)? Do you really talk about a set of *numbers* $e^{b_n z}$ for fixed $z$, or do you rather mean the set of fucntions $z\mapsto e^{b_n z}$?

Comment: @Zeraoulia I edited your post to make it a little clearer. Please look it over to make sure I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: It would *still* be helpful to know about which vector space over which field we are talking (and what we know about $b_n$)

Answer (score 2):

Pending clarification from OP of the matters Hagen raised in the comments, these remarks may be useful.

Suppose $b_n=n$ for all $n$, and take $z=1$, so in the first question we are talking about the numbers $e,e^2,e^3,\dots$. That these numbers are linearly independent *over the rationals* is another way of saying that $e$ is a transcendental number. The transcendence of $e$ is well-known and not at all trivial to prove.

Given one complex number $z=z_0$ such that the numbers $e^{b_nz}$ are linearly independent over the field of your choice, it is immediate that the functions $e^{b_nz}$ are linearly independent over that field, since any linear combination of the functions will fail to vanish when evaluated at $z=z_0$.

Comment: The set $b_n=b_n(z)$ is sequences of functions in the variable $z$. I talk about a set of numbers $\exp(b_n(z))$ for fixed $z$ in the first question and for the set of fucntions $z\mapsto\exp(b_n(z))$ in the second one. Here $z$ is a complex number and the field is also the complex plane.